# Is Java Mission Control included with a JDK?

Tags: java, jmc

Are JMC binaries included in open JDK ? We have openjdk-1.8.0.252 in our Linux platform , but we do not have JMC ?

Can we install JMC as separate application that runs on JVM already installed ? Can we use JMC in production environments ?
If yes, please let me know the path to install JMC for open JDK

Comment: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jmc/Main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## About *Mission Control*

[*Java Mission Control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control) was previously a proprietary commercial offering from Oracle. Oracle then open-sourced it as a subproject on the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. Now available free-of-cost.

See that subproject page, [*Mission Control*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/), and [this wiki page](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/jmc). Notice the “Java” trademarked word has been dropped from the name.

As of 2021-07, the current version of the *Mission Control* project is 8.

### *Flight Recorder*

Similarly Oracle’s [*Flight Recorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder) product, is now open-sourced within the OpenJDK project. See [*JEP 328: Flight Recorder*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328). *Flight Recorder* is currently being bundled with the JDK in my experience, while *Mission Control* is a separate download.

## Java 11

In Java 11, the current [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version, you will need to download and install the binary of *Mission Control*.

Binary distributions available [from various vendors](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc). These include Azul Systems, BellSoft, Oracle, Red Hat/IBM, and Adoptium/AdoptOpenJDK.

Mission Control requires a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) to run. Here is a flowchart I made to guide you in choosing a vendor for a JDK implementation.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

## Java 8

Be aware that Oracle changed its licensing on its product *Oracle JDK*. That product now requires a fee for use in production. As I recall, even before that change, Oracle required a fee for use of its *Java Mission Control* product in production.

Now Oracle has generously transferred the product to the *OpenJDK* project. Since open-sourcing [under the *OpenJDK* project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/), other vendors are free to back-port *Mission Control* to Java 8 per the new licensing terms.

I know of at least one such vendor:

- [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems)

  - See their product [*Zulu® Mission Control*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-mission-control/). This product is included with both their free-of-cost *Zulu Community* product and their commercial *Zulu Enterprise* product.

Comment: JDK Mission Control is also available from AdoptOpenJDK: https://adoptopenjdk.net/jmc.html

Comment: @DavidSoroko Thanks, but I already had that listed and linked by the new name *Adoptium* given to *AdoptOpenJDK* when [it joined the Eclipse Foundation](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2020/06/adoptopenjdk-to-join-the-eclipse-foundation/). I’ll add a mention of the old name.